# Ruby dir path exclude directory from path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

now i'm importing this directory

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/{views,controllers}/**/**/**/**"]
```

but i want to exclude one directory in a specified position

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/{views,controllers}/#All directory but exclude 'admin'#/**/**/**"]
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/{views,controllers}/**/**/**/**"].reject { |f| f["#{Rails.root}/app/{views,controllers}/admin/"]}
```

Comment: @DavideBarison Maybe it won't do what you will expect. Because it not just ignores the admin directory but all the directory which under the views,controllers directory and ends with the letters: a,d,m,i,n.To try it put a directory named 'testn' next to admin and it will be also ignored.